# Binary transformer classification model predicts everything as same value

Tags: classification, keras, transformer, binary, numerical

I'm training a binary classifier using a transformer on structured numerical data (so the order of the columns in my spreadsheet matters). I have adapted the keras text classification model for IMDb reviews (https://keras.io/examples/nlp/text_classification_with_transformer/) but my model is predicting everything as the same class.

After some analysis of the outputs I've figured out that all the predictions are < 0.5, so this is why they all get classed as the same thing, but I would like to learn how I can fix this. As I train the model, I notice that val-accuracy increases each epoch up to around 0.8, but running the predictions always results in everything being classed the same: **why does this occur?**

I have tried experimenting with the hyperparameters but this has not fixed my problem. My dataset is small (around 500 samples) but balanced, and for each sample contains 846 sequential real numbers.

Any help or modifications to my code will be very appreciated!

````
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import pandas as pd
from keras import metrics

class TransformerBlock(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, embed_dim, num_heads, ff_dim, rate=0.000001):
        super().__init__()
        self.att = layers.MultiHeadAttention(num_heads=num_heads, key_dim=embed_dim)
        self.ffn = keras.Sequential(
            [layers.Dense(ff_dim, activation="relu"), layers.Dense(embed_dim),]
        )
        self.layernorm1 = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)
        self.layernorm2 = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)
        self.dropout1 = layers.Dropout(rate)
        self.dropout2 = layers.Dropout(rate)

    def call(self, inputs, training):
        attn_output = self.att(inputs, inputs)
        attn_output = self.dropout1(attn_output, training=training)
        out1 = self.layernorm1(inputs + attn_output)
        ffn_output = self.ffn(out1)
        ffn_output = self.dropout2(ffn_output, training=training)
        return self.layernorm2(out1 + ffn_output)
    
class TokenAndPositionEmbedding(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, maxlen, vocab_size, embed_dim):
        super().__init__()
        self.token_emb = layers.Embedding(input_dim=maxlen, output_dim=embed_dim)
        self.pos_emb = layers.Embedding(input_dim=maxlen, output_dim=embed_dim)

    def call(self, x):
        maxlen = tf.shape(x)[-1]
        positions = tf.range(start=0, limit=maxlen, delta=1)
        positions = self.pos_emb(positions)
        x = self.token_emb(x)
        return x + positions

whole = pd.read_excel('bigset.xlsx', header=None)

wholedata = np.array((whole.drop(columns = [0]).values).tolist())
wholelabel = np.array((whole[0].values).tolist())

(x_train, y_train), (x_val, y_val) = (wholedata[0:500], wholelabel[0:500]), (wholedata[501:581], wholelabel[501:581])

# Define input shape and model hyperparameters
maxlen = x_train.shape[1]  # Maximum sequence length
embed_dim = maxlen  # Embedding size for each vector
num_heads = 2  # Number of attention heads
ff_dim = 4  # Hidden layer size in feed forward network inside transformer

# Define transformer model
inputs = layers.Input(shape=(maxlen,))
embedding_layer = TokenAndPositionEmbedding(maxlen, maxlen, embed_dim)
x = embedding_layer(inputs)
transformer_block = TransformerBlock(embed_dim, num_heads, ff_dim)
x = transformer_block(x)
x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.1)(x)
x = layers.Dense(20, activation="sigmoid")(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.1)(x)
outputs = layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(x)

model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(
    x_train, y_train, batch_size=10, epochs=300, validation_data=(x_val, y_val)
)

predictions = model.predict(x_val)
print(predictions)
conf_matrix = tf.math.confusion_matrix(labels=y_val, predictions=predictions)
print(conf_matrix)

```
````

Comment: Could you provide the 'whole' excel file?

Comment: @IyaLee I'm afraid not, but I can tell you that each row has a label (0 or 1) and then 846 sequential real numbers (8dp precision) less than 3: the order of magnitude of each number depends on the column, so some have very small numbers and some have larger ones